# What is the definition of being offensive according to bibile.?

Tags: christian-living

It is written that pray for them, who hates you, and be good to everyone out there. so if someone is hurting me or Something unfair happening to me... should I reply back. or just be in  myself. If  I reply then should it be considered offensive in terms of bible.

I didn't really get the difference between being defensive  and tolerating unfair to you.

Comment: Please proof read this and then [edit] it to fix up your spelling mistakes. The Bible doesn't really define English words - that's what a dictionary is for.

Comment: I think this is asking for pastoral advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really is asking about one of the basics of being a Christian, and so we must begin defining and explaining the word Christian.

The word Christian was first used in Antioch and literally means little Christ. So what did the early Christians do to cause them to be known as *little Christ*.

Perhaps we can find the answer in the way Christians react today:

I and almost every Christian, who I know, can attest to the fact that our character and demeanor changed drastically when we accepted Christ as our Savior. For the most part we changed from a crass individual to a peaceful and placid person.

So then the defined word of offensive according to the Bible would appear to be any demeanor not like that of Christ.

So what does that mean that we are bound to do as little Christ?

To start with we are commanded to emulate Christ as much as we are humanly able. God knows that we cannot be as perfect as Christ was, but that does not give us the permission to deviate from that example as we desire.

> John 5:30  I can of mine own self do nothing: as I hear, I judge: and my judgment is just; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of the Father which hath sent me.
>
> John 6:39  And this is the Father's will which hath sent me, that of all which he hath given me I should lose nothing, but should raise it up again at the last day.

From these two verses we can derive that Jesus was only doing what The father wanted him to do, and that was to save the lost, and that when we are imitating Jesus we are pleasing God, and when we are not doing what Jesus did we being offensive, not only to those around us, but to both Jesus and the Father.